# Why does .NET Core not add the reference Dlls from the nuget packages to the bin folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

.Net Core projects do not put the reference DLLs from the nuget packages in the bin folder. Is there a way of any properties that helps in doing that?
It's needed for some third party tools to understand the reference DLLs.

Comment: Are you using VS2015 (.xproj) or VS2017 (.csproj) version of asp.net core?

Comment: using VS 2017 (.csproj)

Answer (score 6):

.NET Core, unlike .NET Framework, can resolve assemblies from half a dozen locations. This includes the NuGet cache, servicing cache, runtime store, local app directory, and shared framework folder. During development, these are typically found in the NuGet cache (%USERPROFILE%.NuGet\packages)  This makes it unnecessary to copy referenced assemblies to the build output folder (bin) until you publish your application. For more details on how that works, see https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/corehost.md

You can force the SDK to copy assemblies to your build folder by setting the proper below, but it increase disk use and build time.

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Or you can use the deps.json and runtimeconfig.json file to locate required assemblies.